# What does the acronym "CRT" stand for in the PKCS #1 specification?

Tags: standards

What does the acronym "CRT" stand for in the PKCS #1 specification?  Does it stand for "Chinese Remainder Theorem"?

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: You're right, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I haven't heard any other possible CRT acronym in direct relation to RSA. Sometimes it is used as file extension for certificates, but those are not addressed in the [PKCS#1 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-3).

> This specification supports so-called "multi-prime" RSA where the
> modulus may have more than two prime factors.  The benefit of multi-
> prime RSA is lower computational cost for the decryption and
> signature primitives, provided that the CRT (Chinese Remainder
> Theorem) is used.

Besides that, CRT is always used when pointing out the CRT parameters throughout the standard.

Comment: Kinda awkward that it is not specifically put into some kind of terms and abbreviations